# Square Connect Python SDK Exception From list_catalog

Tags: square-connect

I've been using the Python SDK for quite a while and haven't experienced any issues.

That changed on Saturday (Aug 11) when I started getting this exception from list_catalog

```
..."/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/squareconnect/rest.py", line 66, in __init__
self.data += chunk.decode('utf8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 8190-8191: unexpected end of data
```

Here's a snippet that reproduces the error.

```
squareconnect.configuration.access_token = sqcredentials.access_token
api = squareconnect.apis.catalog_api.CatalogApi()

cursor = ''
page = 1

while cursor is not None:
    print('Processing item page {:d}'.format(page))
    resp = api.list_catalog(cursor=cursor)
    cursor = resp.cursor
    page += 1
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What version of Square's Python SDK are you using? So far I haven't been able to replicate this issue. I tested with Python 2, 3.6, and 3.7 and all of them worked with the code you provided.

Comment: `~ $ pip show squareconnect
Name: squareconnect
Version: 2.20180712.1
Summary: Square Connect v2 Python Client
Home-page: https://github.com/square/connect-python-sdk
Author: Square Inc.
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Location: /Users/dzereski/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: urllib3, six, certifi, python-dateutil
Required-by: `

Comment: I'm still seeing the exception on the second page of results.  Maybe it's something in our data that's causing the error.  Did you try it against our item library ?

Comment: I don't have access to your account. Can you please reach out to our API Customer Success team so that we can test this with your item library? Please reach out via this form: https://squareup.com/help/us/en/contact?panel=BF53A9C8EF68
Thanks!